# Cannot load data file in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, file, require

I created the following parser:

```
require "./artist"
require "./song"
require "./genre"
require "debugger"

class Parser
  attr_accessor :artists, :genres, :song
  attr_reader :mp3


  REGEX = /(?<artist>.*)\s\-\s(?<song>.*)\s\[(?<genre>.*)\]/


  def initialize(directory="data")
    debugger
    @mp3 = Dir.entries(directory).select {|f| !File.directory? f}
    debugger
  end

  def parse
    @mp3.map do |file|
      match = REGEX.match(file)

      artist = Artist.find_by_name(match[:artist]) || Artist.new.tap {|artist| artist.name = match[:artist]}

      song = Song.new
      song.name = match[:song]
      song.genre = Genre.find_by_name(match[:genre]) || Genre.new.tap {|genre| genre.name = match[:genre]}

      #debugger
      artist.add_song(song)
    end
  end

end

a = Parser.new.parse
```

I tried running it by calling parser.rb in the directory, lib, where it is located. I get the following error messages:

```
Parser.rb:47:in `open': No such file or directory - data (Errno::ENOENT)
    from parser.rb:47:in `entries'
    from parser.rb:47:in `initialize'
    from parser.rb:68:in `new'
    from parser.rb:68:in `<main>'
```

This is my file structure:
[image: Screen]
Can anyone please tell me why it cannot recognize my data directory? I have been staring for a while now and cannot figure it out. It was working like 10 mins ago and I cannot remember what I change to get it all messed up.

Appreciate your feedback! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run your example like `ruby -I/lib lib/parser.rb` from the directory above `lib`. The `-I` will set the "include path", such that the ruby interpreter will find the other required ruby files like `(lib/)song.rb`.